# Some type of movement sensor

Tags: sensors

I was wondering is there's a sensor or some type of sensor that would detect itself if it's been moved, say if I put the sensor in one end of the table and move it to the other end it will detect that it has been moved?

I have seen some sensors that detects motion like [PIR](https://learn.adafruit.com/pir-passive-infrared-proximity-motion-sensor/overview) but I think that's not what I'm looking for. So if anyone has an idea of the name I would be glad to check it out.

Even if it's pretty basic it's ok, like there's a receiver to detect the motion or whatever.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It sounds like you are looking for something like an accelerometer, or the more complex version, a IMU (inertial measurement unit).

These sensors measure acceleration so can detect when an object goes from being at rest (stationary) to moving. They normally measure in 3 axis so can be used to tell in which (relative) direction the object has moved.

An IMU also includes a gyroscope so can tell if the object rotates as well as moves.

Comment: thanx i'll check them out.